# derby procedure that does not modify

Tags: stored-procedures, triggers, derby

I'm trying to create a trigger on derby which simply calls a procedure. The stored procedure does not change anything and gets no parameters. It simply check that the time is within an interval (for example between 08:00 and 16:00). On creation of trigger i receive the following error:
"42Z9D: Procedures that modify SQL data are not allowed in BEFORE triggers."
But the procedure makes no changes.

Comment: And what was the **exact** `CREATE PROCEDURE` call that you issued? See: https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.12/ref/rrefcreateprocedurestatement.html

Comment: thank you Bryan the link was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

When defining a procedure one should specify if the procedure modifies data or not. If it executes any sql or not. As mentioned in the link provided above by Bryan I should use one the options:
{ NO SQL | MODIFIES SQL DATA | CONTAINS SQL | READS SQL DATA }
If you dont use this options the default value will be assumed that is CONTAINS SQL.